# A term for a statistics in games

Tags: terminology

In some games there are statistic about how many times user have done something. Examples:

[Cookie Clicker](https://imgur.com/r/cookieclicker/Tu9mw):

- Cookies baked
- Cookies forfeited by ascending
- Legacy started
- Building owned
- Cookie clicks
- Reindeer found

[NGU idle](https://www.resetera.com/threads/i-just-found-a-new-great-idle-incremental-game-for-those-who-loved-trimps-kittens-game.95651/):

- Total Rebirths
- Total Boss Defeated
- Highest Damage Dealt in 1 Hit

It is like passive voice without "to be". 
I am confused with "cookie clicks" and "total rebirths". As "clicks" & "rebirths" are not verbs.

Edit: I am looking for a term that describe how to create above elements from the lists. If it does not have a term, are there some rules?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you looking for a term that describes all these measurements (as your title suggests), or are you looking for an explanation as to why "cookie clicks" and "total rebirths" don't fit the pattern of the other measurements?

Comment: @Juhasz Yes, I am looking for a term. I am just trying to guess what it is but those 2 things confuses me.

Comment: Do you mean 'game stats'? I play a game in which these things are called 'game stats'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul but "game stats" include your avatar's characteristics, like strength or dexterity. I am not interested in it.

Comment: Those are all *noun phrases*. "Cookies baked" means "cookies that have been baked". It doesn't matter that they don't have the same format. All of them can be counted. If you're looking for a technical term in game design that means all the things that are counted, then this is the wrong forum for your question. Try the [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The use of "statistics" to mean numerical measures of a character's properties like strength etc, isn't entirely standard or traditional English - it's jargon, probably originally from Dungeons and Dragons or similar games. Using statistics for a record of things that happen, like the entry on your list, is common (e.g. in sports). You could of course add a descriptor before "statistics/stats" such as "event stats" or "gameplay stats" or "game event stats".

Answer (score 0):

In a game which i used to play, there was a section called "Data" where you could see a list of various gameplay stats, stuff like:

- Doors picked
- Number of terminals hacked
- Creatures killed
- Humans killed

You get the idea. And there was a different section for my character's abilities and skills which was called "Stats". However i'm not sure if there is any general term for these or any rules at all.

Comment: It seems to be <noun> <verb (*1)> <by / in / ...> ... "Cookie clicks" & "Total Rebirths" doesn't fit in that formula.
*1 is it in the 2nd form or 3rd form?

Comment: @DarekNędza In my opinion "Cookie clicks" is just same as "Cookies clicked" , and really it doesn't matter how they are written.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of writing is common in news headlines, where the goal is to use as few words as possible. “to be” verbs are removed from the passive form, knowing the reader will reinsert them mentally as needed. Or maybe they’re just nouns with post-nominal adjectives. The two would look the same and mean roughly the same thing. It gets the idea across even though it may not be clear why it works.

Either way, it’s not grammar we would tolerate in normal writing or speaking, so I’m not sure there’s an official term for it.

Answer (score 0):

With *lists* of items it is often a given that they are abbreviated. Sometimes they will follow a leading sentence, for example:

> In my spare time I go:
>
> - swimming
> - cycling
> - running

You could take any one of the activities from the list and tag it on the end of the leading sentence, remove the colon, and you'd have a grammatical sentence.

With statistics, this can be even less verbose, as you are into the realm of mathematics. Consider:

> 2 + 2 = 4

There's no need to make this any more verbose and say "*the sum of two plus two is four*". The numbers speak for themselves.

Likewise with your game stats. Saying "**creatures killed: 4**" is in effect saying "*the number of creatures you have killed is four*". Statistics often need no introduction, especially if they are on a page titled 'statistics'. You recognise these as statistics in your game so there is no ambiguity about what they are. It is a given that what you will read is the number of times various metrics have been counted.

---

You said that "click" and "birth" (as in "cookie clicks" and "total rebirths") are not verbs. Actually, they can be - *to click* on something, especially in a computing sense, is an action and a verb. Likewise, 'birth' can be used as a verb to mean the act of giving birth, or sometimes assisting with one. Both have an '-ing' form - *clicking* and *birthing*. However, you can count the number of times an action took place and in doing so it acts as a noun. So, "he clicked 5 times" could be counted as "5 clicks".